# Why GeoIP showing error in log analysis?

Tags: python, analysis

I have this GeoIP address code and when I run this code, it shows error that there is no module named GeoIP. This is my code :

```
import sys
import GeoIP

gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
with open ('Desktop/trail.txt', 'r') as f:

  for line_string in f.readlines():
    line = line_string.rstrip()
    arr = line.split()

    try:
      country_code = gi.country_code_by_addr(arr[0])
      country_name = "\"" + gi.country_name_by_addr(arr[0]) + "\""

      arr.append(country_code)
      arr.append(country_name)
    except:
      arr.append("None")

    print ",".join(arr)
```

This is the error :
line 4, in 
    gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
GeoIP.error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `GeoIP.dat` database which is your code using to get information
download it from the official release [Here](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/)

- Scroll down to **GeoLite Country** and choose **Download**
- Move the downloaded file "`GeoIP.dat.gz`" to `/usr/local/var/GeoIP/`
- Extract it by right click and select **Extract Here**
  Or by the following command: `gunzip GeoIP.dat.gz`
- Then will appear a file named `GeoIP.dat` leave it in this path

Now you have the database file in path `/usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat`
try to compile again and let me know if still in problem.

Comment: glad to know that :)